# Regex for m18-99

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a regex that matches the rules `18-99? m? 18-99?`. Here was my attempt `(1[89]|[2-9]\d) m (1[89]|[2-9]\d)` but this matches anything with `m`.

For clarification, here are acceptable strings:

```
m18
18m
m 18
18 m
```

Comment: Try `^(?:(?:1[89]|[2-9]\d) ?)?m(?: ?(?:1[89]|[2-9]\d))?$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Ho3VK/2).

Comment: @MichaelMooney Please update your question with more cases to match and don't match. We don't know how your strings can look like. So you want to validate or match e.g. `18 m testing` and how about `testing 18m` or `foo 18 m bar`... ?

Comment: You can use conditionals with [PyPI regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/#additional-features): [`\b(m ?)?(?:1[89]|[2-9]\d)(?(1)| ?m)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/85QhjX/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(?:(?:1[89]|[2-9]\d) ?)?m(?: ?(?:1[89]|[2-9]\d))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Ho3VK/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?:1[89]|[2-9]\d) ?)?` - an optional sequence of `18`, `19` ... `99` and an optional space
- `m` - `m`
- `(?: ?(?:1[89]|[2-9]\d))?` - an optional sequence of a space and then `18`, `19` ... `99`
- `^` - end of string

If you do not want to match a string that only contains `m`, use

```
^(?!m$)(?:(?:1[89]|[2-9]\d) ?)?m(?: ?(?:1[89]|[2-9]\d))?$
```

where `(?!m$)` after `^`  prevent a string like `m` from matching.

Comment: Hello, I've tried this and it does not accept the string "18 m testing".

Comment: @MichaelMooney I also tested, and [it does not match those strings](https://regex101.com/r/1Ho3VK/3).

Comment: Sorry, I had to edit my comment. My previous statement was incorrect.